# Archiving NSArray that contains dictionaries

Tags: ios, core-data, nscoding, object-graph

I am trying to save an `NSMutableArray` in `CoreData`. The Array contains objects `NSDictionary`

NSDictionary has following Structure

```
valueDict = 
{
    FloorId = F0001;
    endCoordinates = "NSPoint: {541, 413}";
    linePath = "<UIBezierPath: 0x1d0903c0>";
    pointsOnLine =     (
    );
    startCoordinates = "NSPoint: {418, 504}";
},
```

To write to the Core Data I use following code: parray is type BinaryData

```
points.parray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.locationsArray];
```

and to retrieve value I use

```
locationsArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:points.parray];
```

When I try to retrieve it i get following error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (5)'
```

I have checked that NSArray and NSDictionary adopts NSCoding protocol. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: What type is FloorId?

Comment: floorId is a NSString

Comment: Is "points" a subclass of NSManagedObject? Is "parray" a pointer to NSData?

Comment: From the exception I guess that way you create dictionary is wrong. Can you show how you are initializing dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to create either a small test app, or a test method called when your app launches. Create a typical dictionary using the same keys and types, try to archive it, log the data size, then immediately try to unarchive the data. Assuming it fails comment out one or more keys til what's left works. Now you know the problem key and can better determine what is wrong.